# Mocking  Object  issue

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to make following mocking

```
var checkComponent = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IController>();

checkComponent.Stub(r => r.GetSelector().Select(new Position(3,6,1))).Return(true);
```

I am getting that  `r.GetSelector()` is returning null.

Is there a way to make mocking that i am trying to create ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting that r.GetSelector() is returning null.

This is because `checkComponent` (`r` in Stub() call) is not a real implementation of the `IController` it is basically RhinoMock proxy object which implements `IController` interface.

> Is there a way to make mocking that i am trying to create?

You have to specify what should be returned when `GetSelector()` is called,
use Mock for scenarios when you need to specify expectations on methods.

```
var componentMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IController>();
var selectorMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISelector>();

// if you need - specify concrete arguments to return true
selectorMock.Expect(x => x.Select(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(true).Repeat.Any();
componentMock.Expect(x => x.GetSelector()).Return(selectorMock).Repeat.Any();
```